# The process cannot access the file 'D:\test.txt'

Tags: c#

I have a c# code where I need to log the information in the txt file after button click. the file gets created but the write method throws an exception error :

Write method:

```
public static void writelogfile(string text) 
{ 
    StreamWriter sw = logfile.AppendText(); 
    sw.WriteLine(text); 
    sw.Close(); 
}
```

File create method:

```
string filename = "loging-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss") + ".txt"; 
logfile = new FileInfo("D:Log\\" + filename); //for QA 
logfile.Create();
```

Actual line used in the method to log the info:

```
writelogfile("userid: " + id);
```

> The process cannot access the file 'D:test.txt' because it is being
>   used by another process. at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32
>   errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String
>   path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean
>   useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options,
>   SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) at
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String
>   path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options) at
>   System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding
>   encoding, Int32 bufferSize) at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String
>   path, Boolean append) at System.IO.FileInfo.AppendText() at
>   Blocked_listupdate.VisualWebPart1.VisualWebPart1UserControl.writelogfile(String
>   text) at
>   Blocked_listupdate.VisualWebPart1.VisualWebPart1UserControl.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_2() at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated
>   secureCode) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback
>   secureCode, Object param) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated
>   secureCode) at
>   Blocked_listupdate.VisualWebPart1.VisualWebPart1UserControl.btnupdate_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: I forget my crystall ball at home. Please share your code..

Comment: Maybe it's `because it is being used by another process`. Another application or you have an open filehandle for D:\test.txt.

Comment: Matten's comment makes it sound like the way that tulajaram is creating the file is not letting go of the file. With the code, we'd be able to point out where you went wrong.

Comment: ok here is my code...
write method : 
public static void writelogfile(string text)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = logfile.AppendText();
            sw.WriteLine(text);
            sw.Close();
        }

file create method : 

 string filename = "loging-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss") + ".txt";
                logfile = new FileInfo("D:Log\\" + filename);
                //for QA
                logfile.Create();


actual line used in teh method to log the info : 

 writelogfile("userid: " + id);

Comment: Another possibility is the IIS user or whatever Sharepoint process this executes in, doesn't have privileges to non-UNC drives or that directory.

Comment: @kenny: it logs sometimes but sometimes i get teh error, so it shouldn't be issue with the permission

Comment: @tulajaramkulkarni, then likely Matten is right. Why don't you wrap the method in lock with all log operations.

Answer (score 1):

You say the file gets created, but I don't see how? Given the following line

```
logfile = new FileInfo("D:Log\\" + filename); //for QA
```

That path is invalid - there needs to be a backslash after the colon. You can also prefix with @ so that you don't need the double backslashes, if you like.

For example:

```
var file = new FileInfo(@"D:\Log\Something" + filename);
```

Additionally, your error stacktrace does not match the code posted, the filename should have a datetime within it if your code is anything to go by. The stacktrace is showing that the file has the name `test.txt`

Provided there are no other problems, correcting the path *should* resolve *this* problem.

Comment: sorry .. i think to did not copy the code properly,,, the file will get created no issue with it,, but when it goes to the line to
StreamWriter sw = logfile.AppendText(); 
 it throws error

Answer (score 0):

This IOException...

> The process cannot access the file 'D:test.txt' because it is being used by another process

..is as the exception says is because you tried to use a file that already has a lock. You can use the Find Handle or DLL of [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to determine which process has the lock.

Most likely ProcessExplorer will tell you its one of two things

1. You're inspecting the log with some file utility while your trying to log to it.
2. Its your app that has the lock. This means that ,ore than one thread is writing to log. Since this is hosted in Sharepoint this can happen if two requests are trying to log the error.

If its the first the answer is pretty straight forward close the app that causing the problem.

If its the second, suspect it is because of your comment *it logs sometimes but sometimes i get teh error* you've got a couple of options. The easiest is to just block when writing

private readonly object logLock = new object();

```
public static void writelogfile(string text) 
{ 

    lock(myLock)
        {
           //Using instead of close in case there's an error with WriteLine
           using(StreamWriter sw = logfile.AppendText()) 
           { 
            sw.WriteLine(text); 
           }
        }
}
```

The problem is that if there's a major problem where lots of logging is happening all the requests have to wait for the logging.

Another approach is to do write to a file in a background thread but to remove the IO contention. For example you write to a queue instead and periodically check the queue and flush the queue to a log.

Answer (score 0):

By using `logfile.Create();` a StreamWriter is created. You need to close the stream writer (or use the one that it creates) or else you will have issues with two StreamWriters trying to write to the same file.

Just change `logfile.Create()` to `using( logfile.Create() ){}` and that should dispose of the newly created StreamWriter. Alternatively you can assign `sw` to the `Create()` method, and then pass that into the `writelogfile()` method: `StreamWriter sw = logfile.Create()`